# How to use replace in wkhtmltopdf or send value to header

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

First question:

I want to replace a value in the header. I use `--header-HTML header.html`  for PDF header. For example :
I want to pass 3 values to a PDF:

```
date
Letter_Number
letter_title
```

Second question:

Can I use a view for the header? I want to use a view in ASP. For example:

```
CustomSwitches = "--header-HTML header.cshtml "
```

Answer (score 1):

## About first question

Maybe you could use an HTML page as header, as you actually do, generate new HTML using C# code, and replacing existent HTML file content, with the one you have created, just after generating PDF using Rotativa. The other option I can see, maybe a little bit efficient, because avoids generating all HTML code using C#, is that you use javascript inside your HTML to get this values (not sure if it's completely achievable, since I ignore the origin of the values you mention).

Supposing date value is current date, you could use something like this on your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function subst() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            var dd = String(currentDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var mm = String(currentDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
            var yyyy = currentDate.getFullYear();
            currentDate = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy;

            document.getElementById("dateSpan").innerHTML = currentDate;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="subst()">
    <div>
        Date: <span id="dateSpan"></span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And on the other side, point to the HTML in custom switches command. Guessing it is located in a folder called PDF, inside Views folder, you could do:

```
customSwitches = " --header-html " + Server.MapPath("~/Views/PDF/header.html");
```

I make use of similar code for generating a footer with page number and it works like a charm.

## About second question:

I use an MVC action to generate the the partial view that I use as PDF header.

Your code for the custom switches should look like this (using GenerateHeader as action name, PDF as controller and yourModel as the model to be passed to the View, on which you are supposed to store you values):

```
customSwitches = "--header-html " + Url.Action("GenerateHeader", "PDF", yourModel, Request.Url.Scheme);
```

For your PDF controller, assuming PdfHeader.cshtml is the view you want to use as PDF header, the code for the action would be as this:

```
public PartialViewResult GenerateHeader(YourModelType yourModel)
{
    return PartialView("PDF/PdfHeader", yourModel);
}
```

For this PartialView references, remember to include at your controller:

```
usign System.Web.Mvc;
```

Hope this helps, if don't, please let me know.